# docker-ce post installation subprocess never finishes

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, docker

I tried installing `docker-ce` following the instructions provided in the official Docker Documentation [using the repository](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce). The installation got stuck at this point:

```
Setting up docker-ce (17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01postgresql-9.5' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'postgresql-9.5' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

After waiting for a very long time I interrupted the process with `sudo killall apt-get`. Now, whenever I try using a command that uses apt-get it will say the following:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I run that command it just starts running the original command that never finishes. At this point, I just want to solve this without even being able to run Docker (I just wanted to try it out).

I already tried most answers for this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process/15436#15436). I can't even use `sudo apt-get remove docker-ce` because I run into the same problem.

Some info on the docker installation:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor  preset: e
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
       └─ubuntu.conf
Active: activating (start) since mié 2017-11-22 15:38:31 CST; 7min ago
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 1431 (docker)
Tasks: 6
Memory: 18.4M
  CPU: 21ms
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
       └─1431 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://

docker-ce:
Installed: 17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu
Candidate: 17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu
Version table:
*** 17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu 100
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that `docker-ce` is hanging on service start:

```
 \_ apt install docker-ce
     \_ /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 64 --configure --pending
         \_ /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.postinst configure
             \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d docker start
                 \_ systemctl start docker.service
                     \_ /bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --watch
```

Killing `systemctl start docker.service` process should be enough:

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep "systemctl start docker.service" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

check systemd jobs:

```
sudo systemctl list-jobs
    JOB UNIT           TYPE  STATE  
2831057 docker.service start running
```

if any docker job is running, kill it:

```
sudo systemctl kill docker.service
```

Make sure to verify that you don't have any overrides defined:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
```

e.g. overriding command to (used in `17.03` release):

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon
```

instead of `/usr/bin/dockerd`. Before continuing be sure to kill any remaining docker process:

```
ps aux | grep "[d]ockerd"
```

stop remaining Docker daemon process (if there's any):

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep "[d]ockerd" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

If you're upgrading from previous docker version (`docker.io`, `docker-engine` etc.) or just changing underlying file storage, it's safer to delete all docker data before installing new version.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

To fix broken installation, just run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `docker.service` should start.

Comment: `systemctl` shows `docker.service` running. However, it is still running after running the kill command. Same with `bin/docker` process. `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/ubuntu.conf` has the following: 

`[Service]\n`
`# workaround to include default options\n`
`EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker\n`
`ExecStart=\n`
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS\n`

I don't really understand what this is doing. (added the `\n` to show line breaks)

Comment: @Franco you should remove the `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/ubuntu.conf`. Generally configuration in `/etc/systemd/system` overrides configuration provided by package. There were several breaking changes in Docker packaging, so it should be safer to remove those overrides.

Comment: there's a little caveat with your yommands: `ps aux | grep "bin/docker"` finds the grep process itself. But in the end, `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker` did the trick - thanks!

Comment: @Xerus You're right, I've updated the answer to make it clear, that we're killing `dockerd` process.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, here are all steps which I did to completely remove docker. I hope it'll help

Stoping docker services

```
service docker stop
```

Removing locks, after interupted installation

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Restoring

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

If dpkg stuck, from different terminal stop the docker service

```
service docker stop
```

Removing all docker packages and cleaning

```
apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io docker-ce
apt-get purge docker docker-engine docker.io docker-ce
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
```

Remove all docker related files

```
rm -rf /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
rm -rf /etc/docker
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
rm -rf /run/docker.sock
rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Optional, updating packages

```
apt-get update / upgrade / dist-upgrade
```

Rebooting

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue yesterday. I did a server reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

and reconfigured packages:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have problems on `postgresql-9.5` package, I'll try to install `docker-ce` after I purged that package. Also there is a new version of `docker-ce` package available (`17.12`).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and just solved it as follows (origin of my problem was update to docker from older version to latest):

1.- Stop docker service (which is trying to start w wrong daemon command):
systemctl stop docker.service

2.- Modify docker daemon command syntax in (which changed from old to latest version):
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-docker_dns.conf
from:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon ...
to:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd ...

3.- Restart docker daemon so that new config gets loaded:
systemctl start docker.service